# Using Spring Boot 1.3, spring-boot-devtools and Thymeleaf templates won't do live reload when changed in IntelliJ 15

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

Spring Boot 1.3 introduced spring-boot-devtools to provide similar functionality as Spring Reloaded to reload modified static resource templates (html, js) without having to re-run your application.

I have been using Spring Boot 1.2.7 before and I was able to modify my static resources on the fly without having to restart my Spring Boot application.

Same application is now not reloading my static resources.

I am using IntelliJ 15.1. The application is packaged as a WAR file.

I have the following dependencies in my pom.xml (including others, excluded for not being relevant):

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I tried to use spring-boot-maven-plugin with version tag 1.3.2.RELEASE and suddenly changes to my html,js files are visible in browser when the template is saved. It seems that at least the problem is because of the spring-bot-maven-plugin.

I have also set the resource right:

```
<resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.html</include>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
```

Could somebody please help me resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure you were compiling your project? I know I've needed to do that in boot 1.2.x.

Otherwise, I'd check this duplicate-sounding post:
[Using Spring Boot 1.3, spring-boot-devtools and Thymeleaf templates won't do live reload when changed in Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869285/using-spring-boot-1-3-spring-boot-devtools-and-thymeleaf-templates-wont-do-liv/33892269#33892269)